# How to solve this matrix equality in Octave/Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I'm studying my Biomechanics course and I need to reproduce results given in the book "Biomechanics and motor control in human movement by David A. Winter" Chapter 7, pages 186-187 numerically using Octave or Matlab.

I'm unable to solve the matrix equation (please see screenshots):

[image]

[image]

From what I know about matrices is that they are orthogonal (resulting from Kardan rotation sequence `x-y'-z''`).

In the aforementioned matrices, terms named `s1`, `s2`, `s3` are the sines of `theta1`, `theta2`, and `theta3`, respectively and `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` are the cosines of `theta1`, `theta2`, and `theta3`, respectively.

Below is the code I've tried in the Octave-online using symbolic toolbox and solve function.

```matlab
GA = [0.5974 -0.7873 0.1515;
0.800 0.5969 -0.00550;
-0.0472 0.1544 0.9868]

% syms t1 t2 t3 real

% GAS = [(cosd(t2)*cosd(t3)) (sind(t3)*cosd(t1)+sind(t1)*sind(t2)*cosd(t3)) (sind(t1)*sind(t3)-cosd(t1)*sind(t2)*cosd(t3)); (-cosd(t2)*sind(t3)) (cosd(t1)*cosd(t3)-sind(t1)*sind(t2)*sind(t3)) (sind(t1)*cosd(t3)+cosd(t1)*sind(t2)*sind(t3)); (sind(t2)) (-sind(t1)*cosd(t2)) (cosd(t1)*cosd(t2))]

% [t1, t2, t3] = solve(GAS == GA, t1, t2, t3)

syms c1 c2 c3 s1 s2 s3 real
GAS = [c2*c3 s3*c1+s1*s2*c3 s1*s3-c1*s2*c3; -c2*s3 c1*c3-s1*s2*s3 s1*c3+c1*s2*s3; s2 -s1*c2 c1*c2]
S = solve(GAS == GA, c1, c2, c3, s1, s2, s3)
```

The result from Octave-Online (using both versions of code results in an empty structure).

```matlab
GA =

   0.5974000  -0.7873000   0.1515000
   0.8000000   0.5969000  -0.0055000
  -0.0472000   0.1544000   0.9868000

Symbolic pkg v2.8.0: Python communication link active, SymPy v1.5.
GAS = (sym 3×3 matrix)

  ⎡c₂⋅c₃   c₁⋅s₃ + c₃⋅s₁⋅s₂  -c₁⋅c₃⋅s₂ + s₁⋅s₃⎤
  ⎢                                           ⎥
  ⎢-c₂⋅s₃  c₁⋅c₃ - s₁⋅s₂⋅s₃  c₁⋅s₂⋅s₃ + c₃⋅s₁ ⎥
  ⎢                                           ⎥
  ⎣  s₂         -c₂⋅s₁             c₁⋅c₂      ⎦

warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7
    eq at line 91 column 5
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7
    eq at line 91 column 5
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7
    eq at line 91 column 5
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7
    eq at line 91 column 5
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7
    eq at line 91 column 5
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7
    eq at line 91 column 5
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7
    eq at line 91 column 5
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7
    eq at line 91 column 5
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7
    eq at line 91 column 5
S = {}(0x0)
```

Cheers,
SirDickens

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing a symbolic solution instead of staying numerical?

Comment: There isn't any specific reason for going symbolic apart from me not knowing any other way... I used symbolic solve for other problems I had, although it wasn't for solving matrix equalities but rather for solving system of n equations with n unknowns (coming from physical problems e.g mechanics, fluid dynamics etc.)